# How can I set SQL Server Management Studio options for all users?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

We have one Central Management Server from which you can connect to all the other servers we manage. All Database admins connect through Remote Desktop to the one server, each DBA with his own account. Now I want to set default settings for all users. These settings include:

Registering the Central Management Server
Location and colors of the status bar
The format of the tab text

I have changed these settings for myself, but I would like to have the same settings for other DBAs without them having to do it themselves. Is this possible? And if so, it it suffice to have SQL Server rights or do I need a system admin for this?

We have SQL Server 2008r2

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> import and export settings
Then import files on other sides.

Comment: Under Tools I only have SQL Server Profiler, Database Engine Tuning Advisor, Choose Toolbox Items,  External Tools, Customize and Options